# Restrict doInBackground() to Fetch 30 items at a time to populate Listview using json with EndlessScrollListener

Tags: android, json

I fetched json from server using asynctask and populated the listview. The list is too large and taking more time in 2g networks. so i want to use endscrolllistener on listview. When ever user scrolled down, it should fetch 30 items at a time. Can anyone please help me how to implement this. how to restrict doInBackground method  to fetch only 30 items to listview at a time.

Please look into my code.

public class Articles extends Activity {

```
ArrayList<ArticlesGetSet> articlesList;

ArticlesAdapter adapter;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.articles_main);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Articles.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Currently downloading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    Log.i("Main", "finito onCreate");

    articlesList = new ArrayList<ArticlesGetSet>();

    new JSONAsyncTask()
            .execute("url");

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.articles_row, articlesList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}

class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Articles.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            // ------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                ArticlesGetSet actor = new ArticlesGetSet();

                actor.setName(object.getString("name"));

                actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));

                actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));

                articlesList.add(actor);
            }
            return true;

            // ------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // if (result == false)
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        // .show();

    }
}

public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading &amp;&amp; (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            new LoadMoreTask().execute("url");
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}

class LoadMoreTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Articles.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            // ------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 30; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                ArticlesGetSet actor = new ArticlesGetSet();

                actor.setName(object.getString("name"));

                actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));

                actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));

                articlesList.add(actor);
            }
            return true;

            // ------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: I think, You have to implement Paging on the webservice end. You can use Offset=30 and current Position=0(then 30, then 60) parameters in Webservice to indicate the server to send only these results

Comment: try to implement paging in your server call.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I cannot make changes in the server side. Its a restriction. I have to do it in the application code only. Is it possible?

Comment: Will there be any multiple URLs for the paging....how it actually works. Are there any tutorials for that....

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 30; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30 && i < jarray.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: First 30 list items repeated. Thanks for reply. It didnt worked.

Comment: public static int m = 0;

Comment: JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("articles");

    for (int i = m; i < m + 30; i++) {
     JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

     ArticlesGetSet actor = new ArticlesGetSet();

     actor.setName(object.getString("name"));

     actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));

     actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));

     articlesList.add(actor);
    }
    m = m+30;
    return true;

Comment: @sureshch You should probably make `m` non-static. In the case that you only have one instance of your `AsyncTask`, you won't see any problems. However, if you need to create several instances of this `AsyncTask`, they won't perform the way you expect if you use a static variable.